# My 16g USB size reduced to 38MB after make a usb installer for arch linux and failed

Tags: usb, size, reduce, archlinux, drive

Running on Ubuntu 14.04 and I used

```
dd if=arch_linux.iso of=/dev/sdb  bs=4m
```

to create the installer.

However, after its finished and I ejected the usb drive, it gave me a error. The usb size displayed in property is 40MB since then.
I ran a lsblk to check my device:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 149.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 140.7G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1  14.9G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   724M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   1    40M  0 part /media/william/ARCHISO_EFI
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

It can still be recognized as a 16g one.
I tried formatting it on a windows but it failed, and I tried using startup disk creator and erase it, it just showed "erasing",went on and on until I closed it
I tried

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX
```

and no response either

How can I get my 16g space back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rebuild your device partitions table.

Do this to create a new GPT Partition Table with one single 16GB NTFS partition:

```
# parted /dev/sdb
(parted) mktable gpt
(parted) mkpart primary ntfs 0 100%
(parted) quit
# mkfs.ntfs -Q /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Thx, but it still has a problem. There is a partition unformatted, sr0 1024mb type: rom

Answer (score 0):

I randomly plugged my usb drive to my windows 10 and it magically pops up a prompt asking formatting the drive before use. And it works. Don't have any clue what's going on though.